# PHP-FPM - Debian <> Apache - 504 Gateway Timeout Error

Tags: debian, apache-2.4, php-fpm

After switching to PHP-FPM with MPM Event, there are always 504 Gateway Timeout Errors. Apache no longer answers requests. Instead there is a connection timeout. In some cases, requests are answered again after a few minutes, in some cases only restarting Apache helps.

The server runs on Debian 4.19.235-1 with Apache 2.4.38 and 64 GB RAM. There are currently 21 virtual hosts set up.

Last MPM event configuration:
StartServers 2
MinSpareThreads          25
MaxSpareThreads          75
ThreadLimit              64
ThreadsPerChild          25
MaxRequestWorkers        300
MaxConnectionsPerChild   2000